# Python create excel readable csv from list of float values in single column

Tags: python, excel, csv

I would like to be able to create a csv file from a list of floating point values in a single column. Not sure how to achieve this...

```
mylist = [1.11, 2.22, 3.33, 4.44, ...]
with open('myfile.csv', "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(mylist)
```

When I open this csv in excel all of the values are printed with each value in its own column, but I need them to be all in one column. How can I do this in python? Or how do I need to format my list of numbers to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through your list to add rows:

```
import csv

mylist = [1.11, 2.22, 3.33, 4.44]
with open('myfile.csv', "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for elem in mylist:
        writer.writerow([elem])
```

Comment: Thanks I knew it had to be something like that